How to maintain memory load between 60% and 80%?
I have a deployment that is supposed to scale between 5 and 20 pods. For the sake of simplicity, lets say that the pod requests 128Mi and has a limit of 512Mi, so I want the memory usage of the pod between 305Mi and 410Mi.
If the avarage memory usage is above 410Mi a new pod should go up. If the average memory usage is below 305Mi, one pod should be shutdown.
by using:
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: myDeployment
  minReplicas: 5
  maxReplicas: 20
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
        #type: AvarageValue
        #avarageValue: 305
        #avarageValue: 410

and the problem is that im getting A LOT of flapping:

a new pod goes up,
avg load drops below "target value",
pod gets removed,
avg load goes above "target value",
new pod provisioned,
and it keeps flapping all day long until about 1am when service utilization drops


From the first part of the [tag:kubernetes] tag wiki: KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here.

Your HPA scales on CPU and not memory; did you intend the resource: { name: } to be different?  Kubernetes has a fairly blunt view of memory utilization and whether or not this will work depends heavily on whether your language runtime returns memory to the OS (Java and other garbage-collected languages may not), and how much state your application and framework keep around between requests.

@DavidMaze I corrected the "cpu"... since the resources have been decreasing, proven by the fact that the pods get scaled-in, i'd say that is not an issue

If scaling down causes the application to quickly exceed the limits to scale back up again, then your range is likely too small. Other considerations are whether the application is designed to be monitored this way (e.g. GC languages mentioned above), and whether other metrics would be more appropriate.

@BMitch, how can I define a "range"? as far as I know I can only define a single "target" value and if the measured item is above it, scale out, if its below, scale in

@BMitch can you please clarify what you mean by "range"? KEDA and HPA don't work with "ranges" only "target" values as far as I know
